# Iterating through an array in a Meteor.js collection

Tags: meteor

Background: writing a web application using Meteor.js where users can add board games to their profile. There is a Users collection and a Games collection.

I have the list of Games and each game has a button next to it so the user can add the game to their profile. The button will find the _id of each game and add it to a user.games array.  The _id is a really long hash.

On the user's dashboard, I want to be able to display each game the user has "subscribed" to but I'm not sure how to access the user.games field.

Here is my code:

/server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('userGames', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                           {fields: {'games': 1}});
});
```

/client/main.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('userGames');
```

/client/views/dashboard/dashboard.html

```
<template name="dashboard">
<div class="dashboard">
    {{#if hasGames}}
        <ul class="games-list">
            {{#each userGames}}
                {{> game}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{else}}
        <h3>You have not added any games to your chest</h3>
    {{/if}}
</div>
</template>
```

/client/views/dashboard/dashboard.js

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
    hasGames: function(){

    },
    userGames: function(){

    }
});
```

As you can see I'm not sure what goes into the dashboard.js helper function in order to be able to access the user.games field.

EDIT:

So I ran a test to see if the below answer works - I've updated the following:

dashboard.html

```
<template name="dashboard">
    <div class="dashboard">
        {{test}}
    </div>
</template>
```

dashboard.js

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
    test: function(){
        var user = Meteor.user();
        return Games.find({_id: { $in: user.games  }});
    }
});
```

The console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'games' of undefined"

Comment: please post your collection schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding all games for currently logged user

```js
Games = new Meteor.Collection("userGames");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('userGames');

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        var user = Meteor.user();

        if(user && Array.isArray(user.games)){
          return Games.find({_id: { $in: user.games }}).fetch();
        }else{
          return [];
        }

  };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.publish('userGames', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                           {fields: {'games': 1}});
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this out - see my code edit above.  I'm getting the "[object Object]" output into the DOM now.

Comment: of course :-) you need to do Games.find({_id: { $in: user.games  }}).fetch() .. it'll return array

Comment: sorry, I'm actually getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'games' of undfined" error in the console

Comment: are you logged in your app as user?

Comment: because Meteor.user() is reactive you can be facing issue during logging that user will be undefined in this case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, this is working in that it displays the right number of objects, and when I click a button for a new game, it reactively adds it, but each item displayed still says "object [object]"

Comment: nevermind, I figured out a way to get it to work.  Thanks so much!